# How can I summarize rows that occur only once?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query which returns the number of rows of a distinct device_type which occur more than once.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C1,device_type FROM stat 
    WHERE stat_date = '2012-02-08' 
    GROUP BY 2 HAVING C1 > 1 
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I would like to summarize the remaining (HAVING count = 1) rows as 'others'

How can I add the sum of COUNT(*) and 'others' as second column for the following query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C2,device_type FROM stat 
    WHERE stat_date = '2012-02-08' 
    GROUP BY 2 HAVING C2 = 1 
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Sample data in DB

```
device_type
dt1
dt1
dt1
dt2
dt2
dt3
dt4
dt5
```

expected result

```
3 dt1
2 dt2
3 other
```

Comment: doesn't this work for u `SELECT device_type 'devType',COUNT(*) 'others' from stat where (condition) GroupBy device_type having others > 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try:

```
SELECT SUM(C1) AS C1, CASE WHEN C1 = 1 THEN 'other' ELSE device_type END as device_type
FROM (  SELECT  COUNT(*) AS C1,
                device_type 
        FROM stat 
        WHERE stat_date = '2012-02-08' 
        GROUP BY device_type) A
GROUP BY CASE WHEN C1 = 1 THEN 'other' ELSE device_type END
```

Comment: I was on the same line of thinking as this; just replaced the case syntax with "if (C1=1, 'others', device_type)" in both the outer select and group by.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C1,device_type FROM stat 
    WHERE stat_date = '2012-02-08' 
    GROUP BY 2 HAVING C1 > 1 
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
Union

SELECT Sum(1),'OTHERS'FROM stat 
    WHERE stat_date = '2012-02-08' 
    GROUP BY 2 HAVING C1 =1
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Except this doesn't work. You can't apply the sum before you have done the count in the second select.